# Can a web application hosted on another machine receive data from a local .NET application without sending data to the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jscript

Some information:

I've got a USB scale attached to a local machine that's being read by a .NET application.  I've also got a web server that needs to get these scale readings and display it to the end user in a browser window(IE 10).

We have a solution now that does this already, by having the win app send data to the web server which relays it back to the user with a jscript control.  It does the job, but it causes performance issues as the scale is constantly updating and sending data to the server and back, and if there's a delay it causes all sorts of issues.  so I'm looking for a solution that DOES NOT send this data over HTTP at all, but still displays in the web form.

It seems like it should be easy to just have the jscript retrieve this same data somehow but it's apparently not so simple.  There's security issues, among other things.  I've looked into things like Silverlight and ActiveX controls, which seem like they may be capable of doing the job but I was hoping there would be a better(or just simpler) way of doing it, perhaps with jscript directly.  I thought of just using some local file that both of these applications can access but it seems like there would be issues with permissions and synchronization.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Is your performance problem on the client or the server?

Comment: You might want to edit your question's title.  Right now the answer to that is "obviously not" -- if you don't send any data, the server won't know about it!

Comment: Also, just to clarify - the .NET app and the browser are running on the same machine, with HTTP requests going back and forth to the server, right?

Comment: Currently http requests are going back and forth, but the idea is that it would just display what the scale reads;  the scale is plugged into the same machine after all. So no transmission at all(until the user presses a 'submit' button or something similiar)

Comment: To clarify on the performance issue, the biggest one is transmission time.  We have people using the same client in an offsite location, and if transmissions take more than 500ms it causes major issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that you would consider this simple, but it seems as if a more correct way to do it would be to setup a web service on the computer that is connected to the scale and then query this web service using ajax from the browser.

Comment: I've looked into doing something like this, but the issue is that the web service would be hosted as localhost, and I was given the impression that because the web application comes from a different domain, security reasons would prohibit this.  Something about sending ajax requests to a different domain.  This does seem like the best/simplest solution if it is possible.

Comment: Cross-site scripting can be an issue, but in this case that shouldn't come into play. Usually that crops up when you load a form on one server and try to have it send its data to be processed on a different sever. I'm this case, your applications are more encapsulated than that. For instance, your web service could be as simple as a page that displays the output of the scale as an XML string and your display page could be a simple piece of AJAX updating a DIV element with that XML.